# Авторизация бота discord

Tags: http, oauth2, discord-api

я новенький в Oauth2.
У меня не получается добавить бота на сервер через Acces Token
Код:

```js
const guildMembersResponse = fetch(`http://discordapp.com/api/guilds/${guildid}/members/${client.user.id}`,
            {
              method: 'PUT',
              headers: {
    "Authorization": "Bot [client secret]",
    "access_token": key,
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
              },
            });
            setTimeout(() => {
                console.log(guildMembersResponse)
            }, 500);
```

Comment: По-моему, бота можно добавлять только вручную

Comment: Нет, https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/resources/guild#add-guild-member